# Binary search ALP

Tags: search, assembly, binary, x86

I have a binary search program in assembly language. I don't understand why the statement `ADD SI,SI` is used in the again loop.

```
DATA SEGMENT

     ARR DW 0000H,1111H,2222H,3333H,4444H,5555H,6666H,7777H,8888H,9999H
     LEN DW ($-ARR)/2
     KEY EQU 7777H
     MSG1 DB "KEY IS FOUND AT "
     RES DB "  POSITION",13,10," $"
     MSG2 DB 'KEY NOT FOUND!!!.$'
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT 

    ASSUME DS:DATA CS:CODE
START:
      MOV AX,DATA
      MOV DS,AX

      MOV BX,00
      MOV DX,LEN
      MOV CX,KEY

AGAIN: 
       CMP BX,DX

       JA FAIL
       MOV AX,BX
       ADD AX,DX
       SHR AX,1
       MOV SI,AX
       ADD SI,SI
       CMP CX,ARR[SI]
       JAE BIG
       DEC AX
       MOV DX,AX
       JMP AGAIN
BIG:   JE SUCCESS

       INC AX
       MOV BX,AX
       JMP AGAIN
SUCCESS: ADD AL,01

         ADD AL,'0'
         MOV RES,AL
         LEA DX,MSG1
         JMP DISP
FAIL: LEA DX,MSG2

DISP: MOV AH,09H

      INT 21H

      MOV AH,4CH
      INT 21H     
CODE ENDS

END START
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that loop, `AX` is assigned an index of an element in the array, and that index is then moved into `SI`.

The array was declared as `ARR DW ...`. The `W` in `DW` stands for *Word*, so each element in the array is a word, which is 2 bytes on x86 platforms. Therefore, you need to multiply the index by 2 before using it to read from the array. That's what `ADD SI,SI` does (`SI + SI` == `SI * 2`).